# HTML positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I thought that elements aren't fixed by default in HTML? But everything I put on my page (except my header) won't move when I resize the browser window... How come?

I want it to be the other way round! (The header should stay fixed, and the rest of the elements *should* be able to move).

I didn't use any position commands in my css style sheet.

I only used this for example :

```
.container2 {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 480px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/68Cnd/

(Yes, I'm new to html, so pardon my dirty code).

Comment: Where do you expect them to move?

Comment: This is because some HTML-elements are block elements. For example, P-elements will always be placed under each other.  
Some objects need a width to be set, otherwise the browser won't now how to move them. Divs are a good example. Unless you give them a width (and a float), they'll be set at 100% of the parent's container width.  
Also, don't use width: 1200px; this means that that div will be 1200px wide, no matter how wide the visitor's screen is

Comment: Elements are static by default

Comment: BTW: don't place a div in a li

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys.

@GroundZero - how can I insert my logo instead then? I know it's such a rookie mistake to put a div in li but I just didn't understand how to put center my logo in the nav bar otherwise.

Comment: @user3080167 to center something, you can use  

    `div.class {width: ...px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }`  

You must set a width (set it to the width of the logo.  
The margin will center the div by dividing the free space over the left and right side.  
Do not put the div inside a container element (like the li), or it'll be centered inside that container inside of the body

Answer (score 1):

If you have multible little div's and you want that the div's use the whole place (horizontal) you can use:

```
float: left
```

If you have one big div and you want that the div resize himself  by resize the browser you have to use for example:

```
width: 80%
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:fixed;` to #header

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately when I add position:fixed to #header, the header suddenly becomes smaller and doesn't stretch accross the whole screen as I'd like it to.

Comment: Why are you making your body 2000px wide? You should make it 100%, then make your header container 100% and at last you can give your left li's together 25% of width, your image 50% and your right two li's 25% aswell. Try avoiding pixel declaration for a container

Comment: Hey man, thanks! You set me on the right track. I discovered that the .container class had somehow disappeared from my style sheet.

So if I want to give the left li's 25% of width (and the right ones as well), would it be a good idea to break the navigation bar into two parts like this?

Comment: You should never use a `div` inside an `ul`. Also don't forget to close your `img` tag. So, replace the div's with an ul and put your li's inside those. http://jsfiddle.net/pgB32/2/

Comment: Ok, I understand. Will definitely avoid that in the future.. Thanks for your answer.

In the CSS is this the right way to define the UL ? 
`.ul leftnav {
 width: 25%;
}`

Right now the nav bar is actually going down veritcally on my page, I think it escaped the container. So I'm not sure how to put that back in.

Comment: No, you use a . to declare a class. `ul .leftnav` is the right way. like so: http://jsfiddle.net/JPLrE/1/

Comment: Thanks once again for your help. It seems to work perfectly in jsfiddle, but gets messed up when I do it on my PC.

It looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/ujkmmvlsd/1bfb0b7f/

Comment: have you given your `ul{float:left}`? Also use a css reset to reset the browser's style. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ (put it before your stylesheet)

Comment: My apologies - I figured it out. I had put all the ul values in the CSS at the bottom. I moved them to the top of the style sheet and now everything is horizontal. Cheers:)

I just need to figure out how to move the image and the links to the middle of the yellow bar. It looks like this now : http://s10.postimg.org/3q6rhgv95/Untitled_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here: http://jsfiddle.net/68Cnd/1/ . Removed the `body` fixed width, and replaced containers `width` with `max-width`

Comment: Thanks that helped a bit. Some elements look weird though when the window is resized now. They don't stack properly underneath.

Comment: Well, we can help you when you have some issues/bugs, but we can't develop your entire website :)